# Wordpress Hierarchical custom post type automatically added to menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

It is possible this is a duplicate, but I'm not really seeing how what I find when I search relates to my question.

I have created a hierarchical custom post type in a plugin.  I'm trying to get automatically adding menu items for this custom post type, so that when I add a new entry, it will show up in a drop-down menu properly arranged according to the hierarchy.  I'm ok with  having to select a single entry, so long as all of its children properly populate in the menus without my having to manually add them each time I make a new entry.

I've been able to add an entry to the menu.  But it doesn't add the children.  I've tried the "automatically add new top-level entries" option, but it doesn't do anything either.  I found something that said to add a filter to wp_get_nav_menu_items, but either I have it in the wrong spot (I have it in the custom post type definition class), or it's useless and doesn't do what I want.

It seems like this should be something relatively simple to do -- it looks like all the functionality would be present, I'm just not finding how to link it in.

Thanks for any help.

Editing to share entire file after edits suggested, just in case it helps.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( ! class_exists( 'Wrestleefedmanager_Match' ) ) :

class Wrestleefedmanager_Match {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Hooking up our function to theme setup
        add_action( 'init',             array( $this, 'create_match_page_type' ) ); 
        add_action( 'save_post',        array( $this, 'save_match') );      
        add_filter ('template_include', array($this, 'display_match_template' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', array($this, 'match_locations_filter'), 10, 3 );

    }


    function match_locations_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) 
    {

        //$menuLocation = 'MENU_NAME';// Registered menu location
        $customPostType = 'match';// Custom post type name
        $newRootMenuName = 'Shows';// Name that will appear in the menu

        // Do not show the customized list in the admin pages
        // and customize only the chosen menu
        if (is_admin() ) //|| !($menu->slug === $menuLocation)) {
        {
            return $items;
        }

        $rootMenuItemId = 47122;

        // Adding a new root level menu item
        $items[] = (object)[
        'ID'                => 0,
        'title'             => $newRootMenuName,
        'url'               => '#',
        'menu_item_parent'  => 0,
        'post_parent'       => 0,
        'menu_order'        => count($items) + 1,
        'db_id'             => $rootMenuItemId,

        // These are not necessary for the functionality, but PHP warning will be thrown if not set
        'type'              => 'custom',
        'object'            => 'custom',
        'object_id'         => '',
        'classes'           => [],
        ];

        // Querying custom posts
        $customPosts = get_posts([
        'post_type'        => $customPostType,
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        ]);

        // Adding menu item specific properties to `$post` objects
        foreach ($customPosts as $i => $post) {
            $post->title = $post->post_title;
            $post->url = get_permalink($post);
            $post->menu_item_parent = $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $rootMenuItemId;
            $post->menu_order = $i;
            $post->db_id = $post->ID;
        }

        // Merge custom posts into menu items
        $items = array_merge($items, $customPosts);

        return $items;  


        /*
      $child_items = array(); 
      $menu_order = count($items); 
      $parent_item_id = 0;

      foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( in_array('locations-menu', $item->classes) ){ //add this class to your menu item
            $parent_item_id = $item->ID;
        }
      }

      if($parent_item_id > 0){

          foreach ( get_posts( 'post_type=matches&numberposts=-1' ) as $post ) {
            $post->menu_item_parent = $parent_item_id;
            $post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
            $post->object = 'custom';
            $post->type = 'custom';
            $post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
            $post->title = $post->post_title;
            $post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            array_push($child_items, $post);
          }

      }

      return array_merge( $items, $child_items );*/
    }


    function display_match_template ($template_path) {
        if ( get_post_type() == 'match' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-match.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-match.php';
                }
            }
        }
    return $template_path;
    }


    // Our custom post type function
    function create_match_page_type() {

     $matchlabels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Matches', 'Post Type General Name'),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Match', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Matches'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( null),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Matches'),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Match'),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Match'),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New'),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Match'),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Match'),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Matches'),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash'),
    );

    $matchargs = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Matches' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Matches' ),
        'labels'              => $matchlabels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes',),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        //'taxonomies'          => array( 'weightclass', 'division', 'gender', 'title' ),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */ 
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 19,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'register_meta_box_cb' => array( $this, 'initialize_match_page_type'),
    );

        register_post_type( 'match', $matchargs);
    }


    function save_match(){
        global $post;

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "competitors", $_POST["match_competitors"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "referee", $_POST["match_referee"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "rating", $_POST["match_rating"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "victors", $_POST["match_victors"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "time", $_POST["match_time"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "finisher", $_POST["match_finisher"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "title", $_POST["match_title"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "titleupdate", $_POST["match_title_result"]);
    }

    function initialize_match_page_type() {
        add_meta_box("competitors", "Competitors", array( $this, 'match_competitors'), "match", "normal", "low");       
        add_meta_box("results", "Results", array( $this, 'match_results'), "match", "normal", "low");
        add_meta_box("championships", "Title Updates", array($this, 'match_titles'), "match", "normal", "low");
        add_meta_box("referee", "Referee", array( $this, 'match_referee'), "match", "side", "low");
        add_meta_box("rating", "Rating", array( $this, 'match_rating'), "match", "side", "low");

        add_meta_box("weightclass", "Weight Class", array( $this, 'match_weightclass'), "match", "side", "low");
        add_meta_box("gender", "Gender", array( $this, 'match_gender'), "match", "side", "low");
        add_meta_box("division", "Company/Division", array( $this, 'match_division'), "match", "side", "low");

    }   

    function match_titles()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $belts = $custom["title"][0];
        $result = $custom["titleupdate"][0];
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr><th>Title</th><th>Result</th></tr>
        <tr><td> <?php
            efed_select_from_entries('match_title', 'championship', $belts); ?>
        </td><td>
            <select name='match_title_result'>
                <option>&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="defense" <?php if ($result == "defense") echo 'selected' ?>>Successful Defense</option>
                <option value="newchamp" <?php if ($result == "newchamp") echo 'selected' ?>>New Champion</option>
                <option value="vacate" <?php if ($result == "vacate") echo 'selected' ?>>Vacated</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }

    function match_weightclass()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $wc = $custom["weightclass"][0];
        //echo 'Saved value : ' . $wc . '<br />';
        efed_select_from_entries('match_weightclass', 'weightclasses', $wc);
    }
    function match_gender()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $gender = $custom["gender"][0];
        efed_select_from_entries('match_gender', 'genders', $gender);
    }
    function match_division()
    {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $div = $custom["division"][0];
        efed_select_from_entries('match_division', 'feds', $div, true, true);
    }

    function match_competitors() {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $competitors = $custom["competitors"][0];
        efed_select_from_entries('match_competitors', 'workers', $competitors, true);
    }

    function match_results() {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $victors = $custom["victors"][0];
        $time = $custom["time"][0];
        $finisher = $custom["finisher"][0];
        $titledefense = $custom["titledefense"][0];
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr><td><label>Victor(s):</label></td><td><?php efed_select_from_entries('match_victors', 'workers', $victors, true);?></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Time:</label></td><td><input name="match_time" type="text" style="width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Finish:</label></td><td><input name="match_finisher" type="text" style="width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;" value="<?php echo $finisher; ?>" /></td></tr></table>
        <?php
    }

    function match_referee() {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $referee = $custom["referee"][0];
        ?>
        <input name="match_referee" type="text" value="<?php echo $referee; ?>" />
        <?php
    }

    function match_rating() {
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $rating = $custom["rating"][0];
        ?>
        <input name="match_rating" type="text" value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" />
        <?php
    }

}
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are other possible solutions as well, but you can definitely do this with the [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) filter. Below is a sample code that uses this hook to alter a menu. You can insert it to the main file of your plugin, but change the parameters at the top of the callback to match your needs.

Basically this creates a “virtual” top level menu item, and inserts the custom post entries under this menu item. Eventually you could modify it to use one of the customs posts as the top level item, and have the rest listed underneath. Also, the good thing is that based on the `menu_item_parent` and `db_id` properties it keeps the entire hierarchy.

```
/**
 * Blend custom posts into a nav menu
 */
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', function ($items, $menu, $args) {
    // Change these parameters
    $menuLocation = 'MENU_NAME';// Registered menu location
    $customPostType = 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE';// Custom post type name
    $newRootMenuName = 'MY_CUSTOM_POSTS';// Name that will appear in the menu

    // Do not show the customized list in the admin pages
    // and customize only the choosen menu
    if (is_admin() || !($menu->slug === $menuLocation)) {
        return $items;
    }

    $rootMenuItemId = PHP_INT_MAX;

    // Adding a new root level menu item
    $items[] = (object)[
        'ID'                => 0,
        'title'             => $newRootMenuName,
        'url'               => '#',
        'menu_item_parent'  => 0,
        'post_parent'       => 0,
        'menu_order'        => count($items) + 1,
        'db_id'             => $rootMenuItemId,

        // These are not necessary for the functionality, but PHP warning will be thrown if not set
        'type'              => 'custom',
        'object'            => 'custom',
        'object_id'         => '',
        'classes'           => [],
        'target'            => '',
        'xfn'               => '',
    ];

    // Querying custom posts
    $customPosts = get_posts([
        'post_type'        => $customPostType,
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    ]);

    $max_menu_order = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $max_menu_order = max($max_menu_order,$item->menu_order);
    }

    // Adding menu item specific properties to `$post` objects
    foreach ($customPosts as $i => $post) {
        $post->title = $post->post_title;
        $post->url = get_permalink($post);
        $post->menu_item_parent = $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $rootMenuItemId;
        $post->menu_order = $max_menu_order + 1 + $i;
        $post->db_id = $post->ID;
    }

    // Merge custom posts into menu items
    $items = array_merge($items, $customPosts);
    
    return $items;
}, null, 3);
```

Comment: This looks very similar to what I'd already found that doesn't seem to be working.  I think what I'm missing is how to hook it in.  Do I need to make a custom link menu item or something to tie it to?

Comment: In order to make it work, you have to know the name (location) of the menu. In the example above, you have to replace `MENU_NAME` with that. This location name is the one that got set at the `register_nav_menu()` call. Than provide the name of the custom post type also. I've tested it when coded this, so it should work.

Comment: Ah.  And if I don't have a `register_nav_menu()` call?  I've been assuming that `'show_in_menu'  => true` would do it.  Is that something that is also required?

Comment: Every menu in use has a location name, so if your theme is using at least one, it should be registered there. However, to test and evaluate the code, you could remove the `|| !($menu->slug === $menuLocation)` part from the example above. This will insert the custom posts into every menu.

Comment: Only just managed to get back to the plugin.  It works, to a point.  It does indeed show all of the pages in the menu, but they are all on the root menu, not in a hierarchy/drop-down, and they seem to have overwritten what I had put in the menu to begin with (though that may just be because there are too many to show).  

I think I've figured out what each of these lines are supposed to do, so that result doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Followup to last comment.  Looks like once this was added in, it was completely overwriting the saved menu, even in the admin menu.  I would go there and add a link (say the About page), and click the save button.  It would act like it saved, but then show a completely empty menu again.

Comment: To protect the admin part, you should leave the `if (is_admin()) {` condition there. Also, it is just for testing purposes to remove the `|| !($menu->slug === $menuLocation)` to check if it's working.

Comment: Yes, I did that.  After deactivating and reactivating, the admin bit looks fine, but it's still showing all entries at the root level.

Comment: In case you have the rest of the example intact, try to change `PHP_INT_MAX` in `$rootMenuItemId = PHP_INT_MAX;` to an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Done.  Didn't have any further affect.  I have edited question to include the entire text of the file, in case an extra set of eyes can see something I missed.

Comment: OK, I was able to get -some- hierarchy back to the menu by playing with the order in `get_posts`, and now subposts are under their parent, mostly.  Still looks like it's overwriting the previously established menu, though.  How is `$items` populated from the `add_filter()` to the function?

Comment: Aha!  The key was the `$menu_order`.  I updated that to start at `count($items)` and increase by one with every entry.  Apparently it was overriding the earlier items when the order was the same.  Would still like it to be less programmatic and more something I can just add, but it's a huge step forward.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: And I got it running without having to hard code the menu.  See my answer below.

Comment: Made an edit which fixed a couple of bugs - main one was previous code allowed duplicate menu_order values which could cause existing menu items to get automatically deleted because of the way Wordpress sorts menu items.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted dferenc's answer, because I totally wouldn't have gotten here without his help.  With all the details and comments, however, I wanted to display the final result, seen below.  `add_filter` calls `match_locations_filter`, which calls `match_menu_children` for each child in sequence to create the entire hierarchy.  To get this to work, you add any of the custom post type entries to a menu, and it should automatically include all of it's children.

```
function match_menu_children($parent_menu_ID, $parent_post_id, $ordermin)
    {
        $items = array();

        $childPosts = get_posts([
            'post_type'         => 'match',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'order_by'          => 'menu_order',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'post_parent'       => $parent_post_id,
            ]);
        //print_r($childPosts);

        foreach ($childPosts as $item)
        {       
            $items[] = (object)[
            'ID'                => $item->ID,
            'title'             => $item->post_title,
            'url'               => get_permalink($item),
            'menu_item_parent'  => $parent_menu_ID,
            'post_parent'       => $parentID,
            'menu_order'        => ++$ordermin,
            'db_id'             => $item->ID,
            'type'              => 'custom',
            'object'            => 'custom',
            'object_id'         => '',
            'classes'           => [],
            ];

            $newitems = $this->match_menu_children($item->ID, $item->ID, $ordermin);
            if (count($newitems > 0))
            {
                $ordermin = $ordermin + count($newitems);
                $items = array_merge($items, $newitems) ;       
            }           
        }       
        return $items;
    }

    function match_locations_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) 
    {
        $customPostType = 'match';// Custom post type name      
        $ordermin = count($items) + 1;

        $customPosts = get_posts([
        'post_type'         => $customPostType,
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'order_by'          => 'menu_order',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        ]);

        foreach ($items as $menuitem)
        {
            foreach ($customPosts as $match)
            {
                if ($menuitem->object_id == $match->ID)
                {   
                    // This menu item IS a match entry.  Populate it with it's children.
                    $newitems = $this->match_menu_children($menuitem->db_id, $match->ID, $ordermin);
                    $ordermin = $ordermin + count($newitems);
                    $items = array_merge($items, $newitems) ;
                }
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }
```